# Android Mini-PC: How to Autostart for Public Display

Tags: auto-start, android-mini-pc

I have an MK808 Android mini PC which I want to use for a public display.  I can open a browser OK and get the page I want, but when power fails I have to manually open that page again.  I dont want it to do anything else but display that internet page.  Is there a way to autostart the browser and that page?